# Does the length of a pipe influences the flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

if I have a closed system of horizontal pipes, filled with water, where I want to create a flow at some rate by using a pump. Does the length of the system influences the flow ? (in real world not in the wonderful world of the books)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the flow rate is related to the pump pressure by the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation):

$$ \Delta P = f_d \frac{L}{D} \frac{\rho v^2}{2} $$

where $L$ is the length of the pipe, $D$ is the diameter, $\rho$ is the water density, $v$ is the flow velocity and $f_D$ is a fudge factor called the [Darcy friction factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae). $f_D$ varies with the pipe diameter, density and flow rate, but we have empirical formulae for calculating $f_D$ over a wide range of conditions.

So provided you keep everything else constant the pressure drop is proportional to the pipe length.